# Why do I get a Connection Refused for ElasticSearch/Haystack when the service is running?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, centos, django-haystack

I've started the ElasticSearch service and can see it running when I do a `ps aux --sort -rss`. However, when I use `Python3.4 manage.py loaddata backup.json` to update my database, Haystack and ElasticSearch throw up connection errors starting with:

```
GET http://www.example.com:9200/haystack/_mapping [status:N/A request:0.173s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/lib/python3.4/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/myuser/lib/python3.4/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1090, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1086, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 924, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/myuser/lib/python3.4/urllib3/connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/myuser/lib/python3.4/urllib3/connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/myuser/lib/python3.4/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 88, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/myuser/lib/python3.4/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 78, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

What could cause this? I read somewhere that conflicting Java versions might cause this, and I do have multiple Java versions, but when I run `java -version` and `javac -version` they both return 1.8.0_45 as desired.

**settings.py**

```py
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://www.example.com:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

Comment: Try telnet to the URL. Make sure that elasticsearch works on the port 9200.

Comment: Connection was refused. Via the Webfaction host I've now created a custom app listening on a port, say 34567, and changed the URL settings to 'http://127.0.0.1:34567. I get connection refused via Telnet, but curl -I 127.0.0.1:34567 gives HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0.

Comment: @WilcovanEsch - were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: Happily it resolved itself, but unhappily I never found out why. I simply stopped getting connection errors after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like that Java Elasticsearch daemon is not active. You can check this by:

`nmap localhost -p 9200`

And port state must be `open`. If it is `closed` your Java Elasticsearch daemon is not working now. You can check logs in `/var/log/elasticsearch` for errors.

At this moment (Nov 2016) on Ubuntu 16.04 servers to get working Elasticsearch daemon you need: `openjdk-8-jre` and `elasticsearch v.2.3.1` daemon. With `openjdk-9-jre` Elasticeasrch daemon will not start and Elasticsearch daemon version >=5 will not start too.